# is this an appropriate way to close a page for updates?

Tags: php, security

I wanted an easy block of code that i could just drop in my main files to shut certain sites down easily while keeping a way for me to still access them, I'm just worried if the way I am doing it is appropriate to keep access for myself while shutting out everyone else.

```
<?php
if (  isset($_GET['access']) && $_GET['access'] !== 'bypassed' || ( empty($_GET) )  ) {
    echo 'Sorry this area is under updates.<br /> <b>We may be down for a week or 2</b><br />';
    die('We are sorry but we are going have to stop you there!<br /><a href=\"http://google.com/\">A link to Google.</a>');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check ip address is a proper way use `SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

e.g

```
if (SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != your ip ) {
    echo 'Sorry this area is under updates.<br /> <b>We may be down for a week or 2</b><br />';
    die('We are sorry but we are going have to stop you there!<br /><a href=\"http://google.com/\">A link to Google.</a>');

}
```

or you can create a array for valid ip address for allowed.

Comment: how would I check each array item? something like this? `$allowed = array("127.0.0.1","1.1.1.1"); if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== $allowed ) { die(); }`?

Comment: create a array for ip address and check it with in_array()

Answer (score 0):

That'll work, but it's more reliable to lock down the site so only your IP address can access it. If you have logins on your site, you can also lock it down so that only if the user is logged in as you (and any testers you have) then they can access.

Comment: But just for concerns sake, to get past it you would need to know the "access" and "bypassed" words in that order and there would be no other way around it?

Comment: That is true, but it leaves a fair amount to chance. It's better to have a proper login.

Comment: But would this be fit for purpose assuming there may be database connection issues or files could be partially damaged?

Comment: We were wrong! I just realized my security concerns... if any other get was sent i.e `url.php?woops=imin` would bypass the if. I added `|| $_GET['access'] == false` to fix it, but is that enough?